# Is it ok to have WatchOs 2 app running Swift and the iPhone is running Objective-C?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I have an Objective-C project and I'm planing to have Watch App support but I was wondering if I can write the App watch using Swift since the extension code is now running on the Watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can mix Objective-C and Swift in the same project. Apple even produced an [iBook about it](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/book/using-swift-cocoa-objective/id888894773?mt=11).

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I know that I can use them together inside a project but here I'm going to add the Watch extension using Swift so it's different target.

Comment: A project can contain multiple targets. The answer is still yes.